# Kafka streams - Is it possible to update a windowed statestore from within a ProducerInterceptor?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

We have a kafka streams application that does a windowed aggregation using a materialized state store to store the results of the aggregation.

We then have a scheduler/punctuation that iterates through the state store and forwards the aggregated records at a specific point in time to an output topic.

We need to know when those events are pushed to the output kafka topic, which can be done by implementing a ProducerInterceptor.

The idea is that on a failure we know which point to query from on the aggregation state store.

However for this we would need to update the entries on the state store as being processed. Is there a way to do this from a ProducerInterceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.

Modifying state is only possible inside the `Processor#process()` or `Punctuator#puncutate()` methods.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias J. Sax is there any possible way to guarantee that the windowed aggregated events in the state store get picked up again in case there is a kafka/broker connection issue. Example, currently I collect all events from the previous and forward them in the scheduler/punctuator, but if there is a connection issue and they fail to be committed I would like to be able to collect not only the events from the previous day, but all the way back to the time range where it last failed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get picked up again"? -- When an error happens, KS falls back to the last committed offest to continue processing. The previously computed state will be preserved (KS is fully fault-tolerant). -- You can also configure how long a windoed-store should hold older windows via `Materialized.withRetention()`.

Comment: True, but I suppose it won't work when the committing logic is implemented on a punctuator and depends on windowed data. For example, if I have a punctuation looking at a windowed state store for all the events from yesterday so it can forward them at a certain point in time. And there is a failure, then KS won't know what the last point of execution from the state store was, in order to avoid duplicates being forwarded. The only way to do this would be, as far as I can see, to know when each of these events was actually committed (ex: on an interceptor) and update the state store accordingly.

Comment: to summarize my question is, how can I make sure that if an error occurs, the punctuator logic knows where/which range to start from when querying the data in the state store, so I don't end up either missing events or with duplicate events.

Comment: With (default) at-least-once processing guarantees, yes. But you could use exactly-once instead. For this case, the run of the punctuator is guarded by a Kafka transaction and thus either all forward go downstream or in case of failure none, and retrying avoids duplication.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias J. Sax and that is true even if the error happens later on the producer to the output topic?

Comment: Yes. What means, we just cannot give any guarantees. There could be cases (due to async behavior) when the write into the store "is lost" on failure for at-least-once. But the write could also "survive" the failure using at-least-once. Thus, you cannot make any assumption about it.

Comment: Thanks again @Matthias J. Sax, I've got one last question related to this. Are the operations with state store inside the punctuator also safeguarded by transactions? So if I update or delete an entry from the state store inside the processor's punctuator after I forward that record, and there is a failure somewhere, will the next punctuator execution reflect the state of the state store with or without those updates/deletes?

Comment: Both modifications of state and forwarded records via a punctuator are guarded by EOS, and if a failure occurs, the modification is rolled back and the forwarded record (if eventually written into the output topic) would be aborted as part of the TX abort.